# Can PHPMailer determine the precise reason for SMTP failure?

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm currently writing a tool that helps users configure an SMTP send, and am using PHPMailer to achieve this. Presently I notify users if the SMTP operation was not successful, and I'd like to make this more specific.

In the source code, it says:

```
// The reason for failing to send will be in $mail->ErrorInfo
```

However, the contents of this property are not very specific. For example, for both a failed auth and an unreachable server, I get the identical error:

> SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

However, if I dig into the SMTP logs using PHPMailer's debug level 2, I get more useful information. For a failed auth:

```
2018-01-31 19:37:12 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 Incorrect authentication data
2018-01-31 19:37:12 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data
2018-01-31 19:37:12 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

For an unreachable server:

```
2018-01-31 21:12:34 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)
```

So, it looks like this information is available, but it might vary between different mail server types. Is there any parsing of this in PHPMailer? I'd like reliable reason codes I can test, rather than searching for strings in logs that might not match for every server.

I expect there are other failure types as well, such as a badly configured certificate.

Comment: have you set `SMTPDebug = 2`+ you will get some helpfull information back

Comment: Hi @rtfm, thanks: yes, those logs come from PHPMailer's debug level 2. I expect if I use 3 or above I'll get some SSL/TLS debug, but getting the information itself is not the problem. What I would like is to retrieve it in a reliable format that does not change from one mail server to another. My guess is that this is not currently possible, and it is essentially a feature request, but someone may know a trick!

Comment: In that first example, the first line is the raw response from the server, the second is the SMTP class noticing the error, and the third is generated in the PHPMailer class. You will get that info directly if you enable exceptions (pass `true` to the constructor), but PHPMailer's error reporting could use a little love in general...

Comment: FWIW, you can get access to the low-level stuff by injecting your own `Debugoutput` handler, and from that you can parse SMTP numeric response values, which are pretty much set in stone and do not vary much. That only applies to actual SMTP errors though, which are no use in situations where you have network issues, like in your second example.

Comment: Thanks @Synchro. Yep, I'm using `Debugoutput` already to capture the logs. Your remark that I can rely on SMTP error codes is very useful - that gives me some confidence that these errors are more parseable across different mail server types than I thought. I didn't know about the ctor parameter either - great! I will try that.